# Custom AVCaptureSession ( Audio ) , so that microphone data can be saved to disk and transmitted to watson simultaneously

Tags: ios, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

There used to be a `createTranscriptionOutput` function in speechToText Class (iOS-0.6.0 version). This enabled to save microphone data to disk and send it IBM watson server simultaneously.

But I didn't find any replacement function in iOS-0.8.0 version. 
Please let me know if there is any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

New releases of the [Watson Developer Cloud iOS SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk) use audio queue services instead of an `AVCaptureSession`. The change enables several new features and should be faster.

To access microphone data and save it to disk, use the `onMicrophoneData` callback of the `SpeechToTextSession` class. You may find it helpful to refer to [this section of the readme](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk#session-management-and-advanced-features) or [this API documentation](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/ios-sdk/services/SpeechToTextV1/Classes/SpeechToTextSession.html#/s:vC14SpeechToTextV119SpeechToTextSession16onMicrophoneDataGSqFCSo6NSDataT__).

For more information about the switch from `AVCaptureSession` to audio queue services, please see [this issue](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/issues/454#issuecomment-248755698).